# Renaming field in Doctrine 2 without losing data

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

This seems to be something obvious but I simply can't find info by googling.
How can I rename a field in Doctrine2 without losing data (i.e. dropping old field and creating new one)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually run an SQL query against your DB to rename the field.

Although the Doctrine 2 schema-tool exists, it is not meant to be used for modifying production databases and as such does not necessarily perform operations in a way which does not lose data (plus it would be kind of tricky to detect something like a column rename 100% accurately just based on the metadata for the entities)

Comment: So does this mean I necessarily have to have downtime? (While the column name in the code and in the database differ)... I'm kinda disappointed...

Comment: The downtime from such an edit would be quite minimal since it doesn't take very long for such a query to execute (unless you have hundreds of thousands of rows of data).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to rename the property in your Entity class and it's methods:

> #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
> private ?string $old_name = null;    // change this to new_name

... and then generate a new migration, which will give you:

> ALTER TABLE table CHANGE
> old_name new_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

...after executing this migration, no data are lost.